# Update a table using mulitple values from a Ms access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhEo3.png)Please can you assist with the SQL code:

My current sql code which does a count (and works) looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm) AS CountOfBusinessTerm,
                TblField.DomainCatID,
                Count(TblField.FieldID) AS CountOfFieldID
FROM TblBusinessTerm
INNER JOIN TblField ON TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = TblField.BusinessTermID
GROUP BY TblField.DomainCatID;
```

The values of Count of Businessterm and the values of count of field ID, I need to update into the table TEMPTABLESTATS where BTLINK = Count of business term and NUMOFLINKEDFIELDS = count of field ID.

So the SQL that I had to work when I was updating

```
UPDATE TblTempStats 
        SET TblTempStats.EmptyBusiness_Rules =
       DSum( 
         'IIf([Business_Rules] Is Null,1,0)',
        'TblField',
        IIf( 
         TblTempStats.DomainCatID Is Null,
        'TblField.DomainCatID Is Null',
       'TblField.DomainCatID = ' & TblTempStats.DomainCatID ) )
```

Which works when I am populating from a single table with no joins, but now I need to populate from a joined table,

and as one can see my SQL is not all that strong.

Please can someone assist

Comment: Please be more specific. You can just use a `DSum` on a stored query, what's the difficulty?

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to convert the SQL code to rather have the update statement. I can get the select to work, but when I do the update I do not know how to do the select within the update. I would like to change the top select statement to read 
Update TblTempStats   
using the select statement, and then 
updating NumOFLinkFields and BTLInkFields 
from the select statement 
where domaincatid is equal

Comment: If I type it like this does it make more sense as to what I am trying to do:


UPDATE TblTempStats 
SET TblTempStats.NumofLinkedFields = 

( 
SELECT DISTINCT Count(TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm) AS CountOfBT,
                TblField.DomainCatID,
        FROM TblBusinessTerm
INNER JOIN TblField ON TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = TblField.BusinessTermID
GROUP BY TblField.DomainCatID
);

Comment: Please just formulate your question properly. See [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). Comments with code are hard to understand. Post your table as text, not an image, and add expected output based on that table. I really don't like it when you change the question half way through

Comment: Why save aggregate data anyway? This is usually ill-advised. If you can build the SELECT as source for the UPDATE then you can just calculate the data whenever needed.